# Figuring out the power of a YAML file

Tags: navigation, yaml, teleop, amcl, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no prior experience in writing a YAML file. I want to know something related to it's capability.

1. Suppose in move_base.launch file, I have written something which launch mux.yaml (http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_cmd_vel_mux). Which look like below:

**START**

```
subscribers:
- name:        "Teleoperation"
  topic:       "input/teleop"
  timeout:     1.0
  priority:    7 
- name:        "Autonomouse Navigation"
  topic:       "input/move_base"
  timeout:     2.0
  priority:    4
```

**END**

**Scenario:1**

Suppose,** I don't want explicit number in the priority field i.e 7/4** instead I need to **load this value from a text file.** So, I want **priority to be a variable.**

**Scenario 2**

Let's hope that above scenario is possible. **Now suddenly the text file changes; which in turn changes the yaml file as well. Will ROS is able to catch the dynamic behavior of the yaml file and reflect the same?**

***Can you just tell me how to achieve above situations and any good reference for writing YAML files?***

Thanks in advances for your valuable suggestions...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124076/figuring-out-the-power-of-a-yaml-file./) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Background: YAML is a generic file format, and can be used to specify many, many things. In this particular context it's used to specify the configuration of the `yocs_cmd_vel_mux` nodelet, but be aware that you will see the YAML format used elsewhere for completely different things.

I will confine my answer specifically to using YAML to configure the `yocs_cmd_vel_mux` nodelet.

1. As far as I'm aware, you can't reference outside data from a YAML file. That said, a YAML file **is** a text file, so it's easy to modify.
2. The `yocs_cmd_vel_mux` node will not automatically pick up changes to the yaml file. It does have an interface through [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) that can be used to load a new configuration file.

Further things to consider:

The `yocs_cmd_vel_mux` nodelet is a nodelet; this means that it needs to be run within a nodelet manager. It's usually run as part of the core Kobuki/Turtlebot2 launch, but if you're trying to use it on another robot, you'll need to learn a little about nodelets and how to run a nodelet manager in order to use it.

If you're trying to change the priorities of the input topics dynamically at run time in order to force a particular input, you're probably designing your system wrong. The purpose of a multiplexer like this is to prioritize and choose the input topic automatically; if you set the priorities correctly on startup, the mux should automatically choose whichever active topic has the highest priority.

If you're looking for a more generic mux that doesn't automatically do topic prioritization and switching, have a look at the [topic_tools mux node](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/mux).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-01-31**:
@ahendrix, thanks for your comment. I am wondering why nodlet (http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet) is required for   implementing mux.yaml? I have seen here (https://github.com/vicoslab/vicos_ros/blob/master/turtlebot_vicos/launch/includes/_mobile_base.launch); which use nodelet for mux.yaml. Since I am using P3AT robot with lms200 laser range finder; is it possible to achieve desired behavior of mux.yaml. As we all know that ROS autonomous module has limited chance of failure, then what is the point of setting timeout? How we know that mux.yaml has worked properly. Right now, after completing the goal set in RVIZ, I can opt for teleop without using mux.yaml. But problem arises when we try to go for teleop without completing the goal set in RVIZ

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-31**:
YAML is a data description format and is not runnable; it merely defines the configuration for something else.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Concerning YAML and variables (your **Scenario 1**), you can use anchors (&) and references (*). This makes modifying YAML files easier when the same data is used multiple times in the same YAML file (anchors/references [do not work across multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717087/can-yaml-anchors-references-occur-across-files-documents)). In your case, this could look like:

```
defines:
   - priority: &priority1 7
   - priority: &priority2 4

subscribers:
- name:        "Teleoperation"
  topic:       "input/teleop"
  timeout:     1.0
  priority:    *priority1
- name:        "Autonomouse Navigation"
  topic:       "input/move_base"
  timeout:     2.0
  priority:    *priority2
```

You can check the result [online](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=defines%3A%0A+++-+priority%3A+%26priority1+7%0A+++-+priority%3A+%26priority2+4%0A%0Asubscribers%3A%0A-+name%3A++++++++%22Teleoperation%22%0A++topic%3A+++++++%22input%2Fteleop%22%0A++timeout%3A+++++1.0%0A++priority%3A++++*priority1%0A-+name%3A++++++++%22Autonomouse+Navigation%22%0A++topic%3A+++++++%22input%2Fmove_base%22%0A++timeout%3A+++++2.0%0A++priority%3A++++*priority2&type=python). However, if you want to achieve a more complex behavior, there is no equivalent to [xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) in YAML, but you could generate YAML files with a Python script, it's quite simple and you could use a modified version of this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import yaml

def generate_subscriber(s_name, s_topic, s_timeout, s_priority):
    return dict(name = s_name,
                topic = s_topic,
                timeout = s_timeout,
                priority = s_priority)

data = dict(
    subscribers = tuple([
        generate_subscriber("Teleoperation", "input/teleop", 1.0, 7),
        generate_subscriber("Autonomous Navigation", "input/move_base", 2.0, 4)
    ])
)

with open('data.yaml', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(yaml.safe_dump(data, default_flow_style=False))
```

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2014-01-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-01-30**:
@bchr Thank you for the whole information. In the first answer @ahendrix mention that YAML file can't access the outside data. The yaml file you have written gives the priority in the yaml file itself. Based on your info I think its better to write python script which access external text file (for priorities) and creates a yaml file.

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-01-30**:
@Brian Smith: this is what I would do, since conversions between YAML and Python are really straightforward.